# How can I call three different functions based on if my button was A) just pressed, B) being held Down and C) Just released?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing an Arduino program to control a minigun for a friend's cosplay. I need to write a program that when the button is pressed the motor ramps up from 0 to a given value (for now lets say "analogWrite(output_pin,200);") then loop at that RPM until the button is released, at which point it needs to ramp down back to zero.

When I try to put ramping into a loop it doesn't finish the code. I

I need something like this in c++ code for the Arduino button. (I've tried similar things using the "delay" function to no avail)

```
motorspeed = 0 
if buttonpress == True:
    buttonheld = True
    for i in range (0,10):
        delay(1)
        motorspeed =+ 20
if buttonpress == False:
    motorspeed = 0

if buttonheld == True:
    motorspeed = 200 
    if buttonpress == False: 
        for i in range(0,10):
            delay(1)
            motorspeed =- 20
else:
    #shut off motor 
    #Play error sound
```

Here is the current code that only runs the motor at one speed when the button is held down.

```
const int button1 =4;
int BUTTONstate1 = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  //set button to read
  BUTTONstate1 = digitalRead(button1);
  //if button is pressed
  if (BUTTONstate1 == HIGH)
  {
    //run current through motor
    digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    //set speed
    //Rampup 
    analogWrite(9,200);
  }
  else 
  {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  }
}
```

Here is a virtual environment for the circuit

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/cLOBc9JJuTz-copy-of-dayloncircuitrefinecode/editel?sharecode=b6cqTLlNqUCCN09-mQ_zykp5sMnXx6KLt_KNqlXJmcs

Comment: You'll get a bunch of answers talking about interrupts.  A human pressing a button is never going to be a need for an interrupt.  Look at the state change example.  You'll follow something just like that.  The only difference is that you'll do different things depending on whether the pin just went high or low.

Comment: use the Bounce2 library

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using interrupts, it's pretty well documented in Arduino reference:

[Arduino reference - Interrupts](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt)

Most helpful is "Parameters" and "Example code" section. I think you should prepare two methods and attach interrupt to your input (button) pin on RISING and FALLING trigger.

Make sure that the button pin can be used for interrupt (on Arduino UNO / NANO only pin 2 and 3).

I think it should look similar to this (I haven't tested that):

```
#define buttonPin 2; // pin usable for interrupt
#define outputPin 9;
#define powerPinA 3;
#define powerPinB 4;  
bool running = false;
int currentSpeed = 0;

void buttonUp()
{
  digitalWrite(powerPinA, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(powerPinB, LOW);
  running = false;
}

void buttonDown()
{
  digitalWrite(powerPinA, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(powerPinB, HIGH);
  running = true;
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerPinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerPinB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), buttonUp, RAISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), buttonDown, FALLING);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1);
  if (running && currentSpeed < 200)
    currentSpeed += 20;
  else if (!running && currentSpeed > 0)
    currentSpeed -= 20;

  analogWrite(outputPin, currentSpeed);
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I used my original method for determining if the button was pressed or not. But the interrupt and if statement worked perfectly once I integrated it and realized that delay uses ms instead of s.

Answer (score 0):

You could use interrupts to handle pressed/release, set a value, and handle the ramp up/down in the loop.

Keep in mind that you should also debounce the button.

Below is some pseudocode:

```
const byte maxLevel = 200;  // some example values (max 255)
const int rampDelay = 5;

volatile byte targetLevel = 0;
byte currentLevel = 0;

// ...

ISR for Button {    // Could be in one ore two ISR's

    if pressed
        targetLevel = maxLevel;
        // possible other calls

    if released
        targetLevel = 0;
        // possible other calls
}

void loop()
{
    if (currentLevel < targetLevel) {
        SetLevel(++currentLevel);
    }
    else if (currentLevel > targetLevel) {
        SetLevel(--currentLevel);
    }
    // if currentLevel == targetLevel nothing changes

    // if your device is battery powered you could even put the mcu
    // to sleep when both levels are zero (and wake up from the ISR)
    // no need for constantly polling the button when using ISR

    delay(rampDelay);
}
```

This will also start ramping down immediately if the button is released before the motor is at full speed.

Comment: Bad idea. No `volatile` modifier, two bytes variable (no atomicity) - and as far as I can see, it doesn't even need int, byte is just enough for storing 0 or 200

Comment: @KIIV This was some quick pseudocode to show the algorithm. But you're right about `volatile` and atomicity. Both are important - I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that doesn't rely on any interrupts.  Just reading the button and remembering the state in a variable and remembering the time of the last step in a variable to check against millis() (Compiled but Untested)

```
int buttonPin = 5;
int lastButtonState = HIGH;

unsigned long lastRampStep;
unsigned int stepTime = 10;  //  10ms steps.  Set to whatever you want.  

int analogPin = 3;
int analogLevel = 0;
int maxLevel = 200;
int analogStepSize = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);  // will read LOW when pressed    
}

void loop() {

  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    //  The button just changed!
    if (buttonState == LOW) {
      //  was just now pressed
      analogLevel = 0; // start ramp up
      lastRampStep = millis();  // note the time that we took this step
    } else {
      //  Button just released.
      // not sure what you want to happen here
    }
  }
  else if (buttonState == LOW) {
    // While button is held ramp until we reach the max level
    if(analogLevel < maxLevel){
      if(millis() - lastRampStep >= stepTime){
        analogLevel += analogStepSize;
        lastRampStep = millis();
      }
    }
  } else {
    // While button is released (HIGH) ramp back down:
    if(analogLevel > 0){
      if(millis() - lastRampStep >= stepTime){
        analogLevel -= analogStepSize;
        lastRampStep = millis();
      }
    }
  }
  analogWrite(analogPin, analogLevel);
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
}
```